# Kartograph choropleth $script blocked

Tags: javascript, kartograph

I am using Kartograph [Choropleth Maps](http://kartograph.org/showcase/choropleth/) and have a problem with the code. The first line throw the following error:

> ReferenceError: $script is not defined

Code:

```
$script.ready(['kartograph', 'qtip'], function() {

......
});
```

Comment: That's not jQuery please don't just choose random tags.

Comment: You must have such line in the HTML markup before having the code: `<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/kartograph.min.js"></script>`.

Comment: I already added the code `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/kartograph.min.js"></script>`

Comment: Where did you see `$script` being used? According to their [official docs](http://kartograph.org/docs/kartograph.js/) you have `$K` e.g. `var map = $K.map('#map');`.

Comment: You can see this link :
[https://github.com/kartograph/kartograph.org/blob/master/showcase/worldmap/index.html

Comment: It appears he's using yet another library: http://www.dustindiaz.com/scriptjs so you should download the relevant JS file and add reference to it as well. It's not part of Kartograph.

Comment: So, i can disactive this line....?

Comment: If you already include kartograph and qtip yourself then yes, just remove that line.

Comment: Yes, i already remove this line but it'not work...
    colorscale.getColor is not a function

    `return colorscale.getColor(dep_data[d.id][prop]);`

Comment: hello, you can help to me ? thank you

Comment: No, sorry. I tried my best but looks like something basic is missing and I don't have time to start using Kartograph  myself to reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds a little like you might be trying to access through the file system, and not through a web server. Try to use a web server, either hosted or local, like 'http://localhost:8888/' rather than 'file:///Users/PaulSizemore/htdocs/' That might help.